# What sports have field/equipment differences for men vs. women?

Tags: rules, equipment, gender

I was doing a little bit of reading about which sports use the same setup for women vs. men. For example, the [WNBA uses a smaller basketball than the NBA, but the same size court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_basketball#Rules_and_equipment), but tennis seems to be the same. I'm not interested in field events.

If this is too broad, we can restrict to (1) team sports and/or (2) NCAA sports.

Comment: Unfortunately, even those restrictions together are a large list (NCAA lists 16 sports as covered, almost all being team sports). If you were to ask about the differences in one sport or discipline, or generally what consideration goes into deciding the differences, that would be more likely to get a coherent and comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Nij What's the difference between a sport and a discipline?

Comment: How did you get 16? I only count five team sports that overlap and 4-5 individual sports.

Comment: From their own website: cross-country, field hockey, football, soccer, volleyball, water polo, basketball, bowling, fencing, gymnastics, ice hockey, rifle, skiing, swimming & diving, track-and-field (indoor and outdoor), wrestling, baseball, beach volleyball, golf, lacrosse, rowing, softball, tennis. That's 20 (as I hadn't scrolled down two lists fully) even if you count all the traditional and classic athletics as a single sport.

Comment: Depends on who you ask, but a sport is something like a defined group of competitive physical activities that share the same fundamental ideas and mechanics; a discipline is a subset of the sport applying those ideas and mechanics in a particular environment or with additional rules. The above list is comprised of sports; a discipline would be something like the rowing fours versus pairs or the running versus throwing versus jumping events in track-and-field.